# Source code directly in trunk folder or in trunk/subfolder

Tags: svn, directory, revision, subdirectory, trunk

Finally I am entering the world of revision control! I don't have any previous knowledge of Subversion, but have read most of the book, and I am currently installing Subversion and Trac. We will be two developers working on a PHP web application.

My question concerns the directory structure. Common practice seems to be to put the source code directly into trunk. But how do I handle files that isn't a direct part of the application, for instance:

- Liquibase changelogs if we choose to have revision control over the MySQL history
- Small PHP tools that won't be a direct part of the PHP application but is nice to have revision control
- Other raw files/source files that we want to keep revision controlled

Can I add a subfolder under trunk for the application itself -- "app" -- and other subfolders for files that never will be deployed/in production? Or is there other and better ways of solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like you described, it's typical that every app/project/tool/component/thingie gets its own directory, with its own trunk/tags/branches under that.

```
/main-app/trunk
/main-app/tags
/main-app/branches
/small-tool-1/trunk
/small-tool-1/tags
/small-tool-1/branches
/small-tool-2/trunk
/small-tool-2/tags
/small-tool-2/branches
```

You can read more in the online book [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.maint.layout).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! We have two main projects, which may share some common code. We also may make some small tools on the way and place the documentation in SVN as well. Can this be a decent setup (with trunk/tags/branches under each one): `/project1`, `/project2`, `/shared-code`, `/documentation/project1`, `/documentation/project2`, `/misc/tools`, `/misc/migration-scripts`, `/misc/database-changelogs/project1`, `/misc/database-changelogs/project2`. Or should I skip the categorisation folder "misc" for stuff that's not used so often, and instead always place the folders directly under root?

Comment: That's a very decent setup.  Whether you have the "misc" directory or not is entirely a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

To add to dave's answer, I would follow his suggestion to keep the tools, etc., in their own directories.

In addition, you could consider adding the svn.externals property to the trunk directory of the main application.  Using svn.externals can be used to cause svn to check out the other repository directories (tools, etc) into sub-folders of the working directory for you main application.

This can be used, for instance, to allow shared code to be checked out with multiple applications.